# Using use keyword based on if condition

Tags: php, escpos

I am Working with EscPos thermal printing. need to include windowsprintconnector or networkprintconnector based on condition.

I tried to use

```
IF($conntyp == 'WINDOWS') 
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
else
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;
end if;
```

Error : Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

If i use one value without any if condition it works perfectly fine

Comment: shouldnt **if** be lowercase? you have IF and endif is one word. not end if

Comment: `use` does not support `if`.

Comment: You cannot put conditions around it. `use` statements are "interpreted during compile time and during run time" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)